# Can Postie be used to submit podcasts via email?

Tags: plugins, email, podcasting, audio

I have a client that wants me to be able to submit (small) podcasts via an email attachment much like the functionality in posterous.

Using this site I found such a plugin for Wordpress called [Postie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/other_notes/).

However before I try to install this plugin on his site, I figured I should ask if submission of podcasts is even possible this way.

(Of course it's limited by the size of the file you're able to send via email, but that's okay as his podcasts aren't all that big.)

Comment: Well I can always just try the plugin out, but I was just wondering if anybody had tested out this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded Microcast iPhone app which let’s you record and post podcasts to twitter and Facebook. No bells and whistles but easy to use
Microcast.org

Comment: No I want to post them on Wordpress, not on Twitter or Facebook.  (actually my client does...and he's not big on that kinda stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Postie does not currently support posting custom post types by email.  So if you're podcast support uses custom post types, given the lack of response to [this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types-via-postie-or-email) the answer appears to be no.

It does, however, support posting attachments by email.  If it uses regular post types with a media attachment, or embedded 3rd-party video, then the answer is probably yes, although you may have to create a custom filter to process any custom fields properly.  From the FAQ:

> **Can I select tags or categories based on the content of the e-mail?**
>
> Yes. You can create your own function, and use the postie_post filter. See the filterPostie.php.sample file for examples.
>
> **How can I embed youtube or vimeo videos?**
>
> Simply put the url in the body of your e-mail. (Make sure that you have the option to convert url into links turned on)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that postie can be used to do this.

Comment: Why not mark this as the answer then? A fuller explanation would be great as well.